# Reset boolean value to false after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Got a rails app here with a basic form being submitted via Ajax. After the form has been submitted I am using the following code to reset a text form field:

> $('#pitcher_game_stat_innings_pitched').val('')

This code works. I am now looking to similarly reset a few boolean fields back to unchecked.
Something like this

> $('pitcher_game_stat_complete_game').val(false)

What is the javascript method to change a boolean value back to false (unchecked)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set property states like checked

```
$('#pitcher_game_stat_complete_game').prop('checked', false)
```